# Extending Parse.User to a custom user class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/)'s JavaScript SDK. I'd like to have my custom user class which has a some instance methods, some class method that encapsulates creation of a user. My code so far looks like this:

```
var CustomUser = Parse.User.extend({
    foo: function () {
    },
    bar: function () {
    }
}, {
    create: function (username, password, email) {
        var user = new Parse.User();

        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password)
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.save();

        return user;
    }
});
```

I'd like to be able to use it as follows:

```
var someUser = BlogUser.create('foo', 'bar', 'foo@bar.com');
someUser.foo();
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work as I'm returning an instance of the `Parse.User()` class, which doesn't have my instance methods `foo()` and `bar()` attached to its prototype. I tried calling the `setUsername()`, `setPassword()` etc. on `this`, but this doesn't work as well (fairly obvious, because JavaScript doesn't know that my class actually inherits `Parse.User`). Apparently `Parse.User.extend` isn't properly documented, so I'm pretty much experimenting. So my question is, what's the proper way to achieve all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in JavaScript I can instantiate an object while defining it, so the solution is to instantiate `CustomUser` in the `create` function (instead of `Parse.User`), act on it and then return that instance. That way I extend the `Parse.User` object while having my custom logic.